# TypeError: Not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python

I have code:

```
with open('D:\\Downloads\\Train_rev1.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    data.next()
    records = ",".join('({}, {})'.format(row[0], row[1]) for row in data)
print 'inserting records into {} ...'.format('train_rev1')
result = conn.execute("INSERT INTO train_rev1 (id, title) VALUES {}".format(records))
print 'Records inserted into {} {}'.format('train_rev1', 'successful' if result else 'unsuccessful')
```

and I got

```
> inserting records into train_rev1 ... Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "I:\test\IceSugar\test.py", line 81, in <module>
>     insert_trainRev1Records(conn)   File "I:\test\IceSugar\test.py", line 54, in insert_trainRev1Records
>     result = conn.execute("INSERT INTO train_rev1 (id, title) VALUES {}".format(records))   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1449, in execute
>     params)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1628, in _execute_text
>     statement, parameters   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py",
> line 1691, in _execute_context
>     context)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.7.9-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py",
> line 331, in do_execute
>     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4c1-py2.7-win32.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
> line 183, in execute
>     query = query % db.literal(args) TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I have no idea, what is wrong?

Comment: That code won't ever raise that error. Is that your exact code? At best I'd expect an IndexError instead.

Comment: Please post the full traceback (and more code).

Comment: if data is correct this should work, something like [[1,2],[3,4]]?

Comment: The only way any data will raise such an error is to have `__getitem__` overridden on rows with a method that uses broken formatting. Or `__iter__` on `data`. Both are very unlikely.

Comment: Oooh, or `__str__` on row items. This is more likely.

Comment: run with pdb and check the values of `query` and `args` where it breaks/raises.

Comment: Okay, this is a totally different matter. You are feeding unescaped titles into your database, confusing it greatly. Do your titles have question marks? To write write correct code we'll need to know what database you are using.

Comment: I use MySQL. There is about 250 000 rows, so title could have question marks, I dont know...

Comment: Congratulations, @DavidSilva, you have discovered the [SQL injection attack](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: The Python Debugger: http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine to me:

```
>>> data = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> records = ",".join("({0}, {1})".format(row[0], row[1]) for row in data)
>>> records
'(1, 2),(3, 4)'
```

Assuming of course that `data` has the format I deduced.

So my guess is that you have a problem wit the format of your `data` object or you didn't post actual code.